# Assets library - best practices inc sharing a model with parent/child

Tags: asset-browser

I'm back using Blender again after about 15 years!

I'm building up an asset library of 'blocks' and simple models to use in a variety of scenes. But not sure I'm going about things in the best way.

1: simple blocks, I'm marking as assets, then in my other blender file with the scenes, I'm viewing the asset library, setting it to 'link' and dragging the assets in. I can't move these assets, so I click object -> relations -> make library override. This seems to work well, I can set the materials, but the object is still linked to the original

2: However, I have some simple models which are parented. Eg, a robot made of basic cubes, the legs, arms, head parented to the torso, and a 'face' (plane with A material) attached to the head using a shrinkwrap modifier. I'm struggling to see how to place this model into my scene, ideally while being able to perfect the original asset over time.

Comment: In this case I think the best is to use Collection Assets (possbile only in Blender 3.2 +) however you'll have to instance it in your work file if you want to tweak it afterwards

Answer (score 0):

If you build an asset file, where you mark the objects as Asset, you must import those objects in your work file setting in the preferences the asset library file, than open the asset browser window and simply drag and drop the object in the scene.
At the moment working with parented object have some limitation, so the best way at the moment seems to be to move the parented object in a separate collection and mark that as asset, so you will get all the parts in one single object in the browser, if you need to edit it you must use the "make instance real" command and than recreate the parent.